# Equilibrium index of an array of large numbers, how to prevent overflow?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

**Problem statement:**
An *equilibrium index* of an array is an index into the array such that the sum of elements at lower indices is equal to the sum of elements at higher indices.
For example, in {-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0}, 3 is an equilibrium index, because:
    -7 + 1 + 5 = -4 + 3 + 0

Write a function that, given an vector of ints, returns its equilibrium index (if any). Assume that the vector may be very long.

**Question:**
All solutions (efficient), that I found are based on the fact that given the sum of all elements and current running sum of one part we can obtain via deduction sum of elements of residual part.
I don't think that solutions are correct, because if we provide large vector with MAX_INT elements, sum of elements will result on an overflow.
**How issue with an overflow can be solved?**
references on suggested solutions, all of them fail to address overflow issue
(I am referring only to C++ implementation, in Java as far as I know BigInteger class exist that solves it)
http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html
Supplementary material:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<size_t> equilibrium(T first, T last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_t;

    value_t left  = 0;
    value_t right = std::accumulate(first, last, value_t(0));
    std::vector<size_t> result;

    for (size_t index = 0; first != last; ++first, ++index)
    {
        right -= *first;
        if (left == right)
        {
            result.push_back(index);
        }
        left += *first;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    const int data[] = { -7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0 };

    std::vector<size_t> indices(equilibrium(data, data + 7));

    std::for_each(indices.begin(), indices.end(), print<size_t>);
}
```

Comment: Link to the [problem statement](https://codility.com/contests/shortEqui2011/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that ultimately it can't be completely cured/solved, unless you limit the number/magnitude of the inputs--not even with something like Java's BigInt (or equivalents for C++ such as gmp, NTL, etc.)

The problem is pretty simple: the memory in any computer is finite. There will always be some finite limit on the numbers we can represent. An arbitrary precision integer type can increase the limit to numbers far larger than most of use work with on a regular basis, *but* regardless of what the limit might be, there will always be dramatically larger numbers that can't be represented (at least without changing to some other representation--but if we're going to have precision to the units place for arbitrary numbers, there are distinct limits on how clever we can get in representing gargantuan numbers).

For the conditions given in the linked problem, the `long long` type in C and C++ is adequate. If we want to increase the limit to some ridiculous size with a solution in C++, it's pretty simple. Although they're not a required part of a C++ implementation, there are many arbitrary precision integer libraries available for C++.

I suppose there *could* be some way to compute an answer to this problem that doesn't involve actually summing the numbers--but at least at first glance, this idea doesn't seem very promising to me. The statement of the problem is specifically about computing sums. While you could certainly carry out various machinations to keep the summing from *looking* like summing, the fact is that the basic statement of the problem involves sums, which tends to suggest that solutions that don't involve sums may well be difficult to find.

Comment: My point of view is: yes we can't compute sum, due to the limited precision, as you mentioned, but might exist method where we don't compute that sum??? One can try to play with difference, logs ... So my question is not about sum of unlimited numbers, rather of another approach that avoids usage of sum

Comment: @spin_eight: I've added a bit about this to the answer.

Comment: yes, thank you I noticed your changes. While posting my question I hoped for more rigorous answer than the answer like "could be... at first glance". While statement based on sum, the problem might be reduced to one where is no sum

Comment: @spin_eight: It's essentially impossible to prove that no such approach could exist, so unless somebody devises a method that doesn't involve summing the numbers, about the best anybody can do is admit that they don't know of such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Notice that if `data[0] < data[len - 1]`, then `data[1]` shall belong to the "left" part; similarly if `data[0] > data[len-1]` then `data[len-2]` belongs to the "right" part. This observation allows an inductive proof of correctness of the following algorithm:

```
left_weight = 0; right_weight = 0
left_index = 0; right_index = 0

while left_index < right_index
    if left_weight < right_weight
        left_weight += data[left_index++];
    else
        right_weight += data[--right_index]
```

Still there is an accumulation, but it is easy to deal with by keeping track of imbalance and a boolean indicator of which side is heavier:

```
while left_index < right_index
    if heavier_side == right
        weight = data[left_index++]
    else
        weight = data[--right_index]

    if weight < imbalance
        imbalance = imbalance - weight
    else
        heavier_side = !heavier_side
        imbalance = weight - imbalance
```

At least for unsigned `data` there is no possibility of overflow. Some tinkering might be required for signed values.

Comment: 1-st part left_weight += data[left_index++]; - overflow might occure; in the second part how you find which side is heavier?

Comment: It is decided by comparing weight to imbalance. If weight is larger, the imbalance goes to the other side, and it becomes heavier, otherwise the imbalance just diminishes.